# How can I order items in my DOM when they aren't ngRepeated in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a `controller` that contains 2 different `controllers`: a `users` and `classes` model.

I'd like them to stay on the top according to the chronological order in which they were opened (e.g. if you open `Users` then `Classes`, `Classes` should appear above `Users`, even though in the html template, the `Users` section appears first). Here's a JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/IQUDEdI/10/edit

When you click a checkbox to open one section, it `unshift`s it to `array $scope.openSections`. I realized that `ngFilter` doesn't work unless it's within a `ngRepeat` (right?).

If there's not a built-in way to do it (I was looking at `ngSwitch`, but that doesn't look like what I want), I was going to create (or rather modify) a directive on `section` that would do a `$(body).prepend(element)` or something, although I'm not sure if that'd 100% work.

Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ng-order is not part of angularjs. Are you sure it is called?

Comment: Yeah, I realized it wasn't. It should have been part of a `filter`, but I think I can only apply filters to `ngRepeat`s, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a very nice question.

Basically, we need a directive which can show, hide and sort a list of sections on every change.
Our directive must **"know"** all the sections it contains in order to sort them.

Oh, there is such a directive : `ngRepeat`, But how can we provide it a list of sections?
If these "sections" are just **`DOM nodes`** there is no way to pass them into `ngRepeat`.

So, I tried to create a directive (container) which collects all the *`DOM NODES`* , watch the collection and on change sorts, shows or hides the relevant sections. 
But that kind of manipulation of `DOM nodes`  is a real pain and I felt it's a wrong way to go.

#### And then I saw the light!

Just refactor the markup a little bit by using `ngInclude` to declare the templates.
then use `ngRepeat` to iterate these templates, so nice.

#### Now it's a great win:

- No custom directive needed.
- All the benefits of `ngRepeat` / `ngInclude` goodies
- No need to set a different watch on each section, `ngRepeat` will take care of it.
- simple and clear!

Here is a **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ilwdfyirsAlMrY0SLAQ4?p=preview):**

#### Declaring templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="users.section">
  <div ng-controller='usersviewer'>
    <legend>Users</legend>
    <li ng-repeat='user in users'>{{user.name}}</li>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="classes.section">
  <div ng-controller='classesviewer'>        
    <legend>Classes</legend>
    <li ng-repeat="class in classes">{{class}}</li>    
  </div>
</script>
```

#### Using `ngRepeat` to do all the "magic":

```
<div class='section' ng-repeat="include in openSections" ng-include="include + '.section'">
</div>
```

#### Bonus - refactored the css to match `ngInclude` animations:

```
.section {
  background:darkgray;
  color:white;

  /* Default fully visible value */
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.section.ng-leave {
  /* Declare transitions */
  display:block !important;
  transition: all 0.2s;

  /* Value when fully visible */
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}

.section.ng-leave-active {
  /* Value when invisible */
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

.section.ng-enter {
  /* Declare transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display:block !important;

  /* Value when invisible */
  opacity: 0;
  height:0px;
}

.section.ng-enter-active {
  /* Value when fully visible */
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Boom! You know your stuff! Thanks for the detailed reply! I've used `ngTemplate` a bit before but didn't think of using it here. Thanks again!

Comment: Darn, I found one issue. It looks like template creates a new instance each time. I guess by nature this is a requirement of using templating? Thanks, though!

Comment: I will look into it later.

Comment: Oh don't worry about it. In the meantime, I've just saved a few things to its parent `ngController`, and loading from memory if loaded once. Thanks again